# Prevent browser from fetching AngularJS properties in HTML syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My HTML syntax has embedded AngularJS model properties, such as this:

```
<img class="media-object" src="[[[post.creative.author.selfie]]]" alt>
```

Although the app does work as expected, opening the page with the dev tools shows that the browser first tries to fetch the resources with this literal syntax, and thus the console is full of errors such as this one:

```
http://localhost:3000/[[[comment.author.selfie]]] 404 (Not Found)
```

I have looked at the AngularJS documentation but have not been able to find a way to prevent the browser from trying to download these resources before the Angular app is loaded.

Any help on how to avoid these 404 errors will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `ng-src` istead of `src`.